# Screen orientation forced to portrait, but still, the activities will rotate to landscape when tilted!! How to force portrait mode?

Tags: android

I've searched stackoverflow for this and didn't get any solution to what I am looking for.

In my manifest file I am writing the following line for each activity

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

But still, all the activities rotate to landscape on tilting the phone.

How can I solve this issue ?

"Once upon a time I was a confident developer in C/C++,iOS,Java,Javascript,C# but thank you android! now I can't even look eye to eye in mirror!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be this will help

In your manifest file after your main activity write below line

```
 android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Or in your coding after setContentView() add this line..

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Comment: I have written this line in all activities including the main activity. But still nothing works. Now I'll try writing the setRequestedOrientation and see.

Comment: thanks, the coding of setRequestedOrienation is working. But I do not understand, why have they given an option in manifest file to set screenOrientation when it actually only works with coding ?